# how to use phoenix transaction with jdbc client

Tags: jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am using phoenix with transactions, as from [phoenix.apache.org/transactions.html](https://phoenix.apache.org/transactions.html), I need to set phoenix.transactions.enabled=true from my client-side.

But how to set that in a java jdbc client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
Properties info = new Properties();
info.setProperty("phoenix.transactions.enabled", Boolean.TRUE.toString());    
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);
```